# Anomalous mysql behaviour on replace query

Tags: mysql, replace

im using a v simple database and i have 3 columns A(bigINT 20) , B(bigInt 20) and c(DECIMAL(5,4)) , when i fire the following query i get the below mentioned results :

```
REPLACE INTO `my_table` SET `A` = 8,`B` = 44,`C` = 14;
```

i get these values in mysql A =8 , b= 44 and c as 9.9999 ! ?

any ideas as to why is this happening and what can i do to resolved this ?

Comment: does your table has only one row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DECIMAL(5,4)` means that the number has at most `5` digits, `4` of them after decimal point. So `14` is simply overflow as it would require `DECIMAL(6,4)`.

It must be cleared that `14` is overflow, because as constant precision point decimal it is internally `14.0000` here (so six digits over five).

So if you try to put `14.0000` (six digits) in `DECIMAL(5,4)` (five digits max) -> MySQL chooses value closest to the one you request. Therefore `14.0000` gets "rounded" to `9.9999`.

To fit `14` in your column you can either extend it do `DECIMAL(6,4)` (to allow more digits in general) or change to `DECIMAL(5,3)` (which will allow one more digit before decimal point, but loses some precision of course).

Comment: why is 5 an overflow , 14 has 2 digits isnt it ?

Comment: No. With 4 digists after decimal point, 14 is actually 14.0000. Six digits.

Comment: Btw. I simply love MySQL for such kind of flaws... I can hardy imagine a scenario when a developer would like database server to round 14 down to 9.9999 in decimal column, instead of throwing "your-design-estimates-were-wrong" error...

Comment: ok im really lost , im still no where near why is 14 -> 9.999 ?, 5,4 means i can add 5 digits max before the decimal and 4 after it ?

Comment: Updated answer. Hope it's clear now. No, 5.4 means you can have 5 digists at all (counting both before and after decimal point).

Comment: uhmm no , im really not getting this one , why 14 has 2 digits lesser than 5 digits that is my max limit ,why would it round off ?

Comment: Compare two numbers: `14.0000` and `9.9999`. Which of them has less digits?

Comment: sure 9.9999 has lesser , but im not getting the very reason y its considering 9.9999 when 14 = 2 digits is < 5 digits permitable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15572/discussion-between-user1537158-and-kuba-wyrostek)

Comment: And I wrote it in my second comment. `14` is `14` for you, but as long as you wish to put it into `DECIMAL(5,4)` column it gets internally converted to `DECIMAL(?,4)` type and thus is represented internally as `14.0000` which has 6 digits.